# VBA macro function not filling down to last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro formula that is checking the customer name and the customer number of column A and B respectively, if the number of characters is superior than 30, it should erase some spaces and only consider 15 of them, otherwise it should copy the name and the number.

The code is running correctly but it's only reflecting on the first row of the column, it is not applying until the end.

```
Range("E2", Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(XLOOKUP(RC[-3],DB!C[1],DB!C[-2])=0,""NO EMAIL"",XLOOKUP(RC[-3],DB!C[1],DB!C[-2]))"
    Range("H2", Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(CONCATENATE(RC[-7],""-"",RC[-6])>30),CONCATENATE(LEFT(RC[-7],15),""-"",RC[-6]),CONCATENATE(RC[-7],""-"",RC[-6]))"
```

I added the code from Column E, that is running correctly, but the one on column H is not applying to the rows below.

[Image of the code running and only applying to one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkw7u.png)

I tried using .FillDown at the end of the code line

Comment: Btw, don't hard-code the row number: `Range("C65536") -> Range("C" & Rows.Count)`.

Comment: You're finding the last row based on column F, not column C. Change `Range("F65536")` to `Range("C" & Rows.Count)`.